# Error when configuring session state server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, session, state-server, appfabric

We are trying to setup session state server. When we do, we get the following error:

> Message: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 217.18.207.181:80
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>      at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)

Note the IP address in the error message is the IP of the load balancer, but when we do a trace between the servers it does not go via the load balancer.

We have also tried using AppFabric but then we get the following error:

> Message: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: lockHandle
>      at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.Unlock(String key, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheSessionStoreProvider.ReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, Object lockId)
>      at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Any help would be much appreciated.